# Issues with fade out HR line

Tags: html, css

So I recently switched hosts, but my previous hosting provider did not give me the most up to date files, so I basically have had to re do a lot of things. One of them is the fade out HR tag under "Welcome to my Blog" in the sidebar. http://travisingram.net/

It should go from yellow to white as it looks, but the issue is now it has a small bit of white on the outer part of the HR tag. Also the black in the line still goes all the way into the yellow, I can't figure out how I made it have full Golden Yellow, then go to black...

Also whenever the page moves up or down (caused by the image slider by its self), the HR line width shakes around, it may not be noticeable to others, but it really bugs me personally.

My CSS:

```
margin: 0px 0;
height: 1.4px;
background: black;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F),       color-stop(100%, black));
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F), color-stop(100%, black));
background:  linear-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F), color-   stop(100%, black));
```

My site: http://travisingram.net/

I can't go back and do cache or use waybackmachine because I have the site not craw-able so I can work on the site and not deal with Google trying to see it as a site with a bunch of random useless stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `border:0;` to `<hr>`.

This should solve your problem.